# How can I make this query more generic?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
select 
  some_id
from 
  tablename t
where 
  t.end_date < current_date
  and not exists (
    select null
    from tablename ti
    where ti.end_date > t.end_date
      and ti.some_id = t.some_id
      and ti.some_criteria = t.some_criteria
  )
```

How can I change this so that I can query it for any date without having to change the query on the inside? (replace the "current_date" with a value)

I'm not looking for a PL/SQL answer, as I want to put this in a view...

Comment: You mean you just want to specify the date when you execute a query against the view? Then you'll have to remove the `end_date < current_date` from the `WHERE` clause and just apply it when you SELECT from the view, as far as I know...

Comment: A view is not like a function. You cannot pass parameters into a view. The view contains a fixed query which can't alter its behavior depend on some kind of input. You're going to need a stored procedure to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yeah, the environment I'm working in is super paranoid about pl/sql procs, and I've been told to try to make it work as a view for date n.  Changing this to be a proc should be REALLY simple, it's just not the solution that the stakeholder prefers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you said you don't want to use PL/SQL, the best option would be to create a (pipelined) table function.

It's a bit more complicate to setup than a view, but once created, you could use the function "like" a view with parameters:

```
SELECT *
FROM table(get_stuff(current_date));
```

Here are some examples:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm#sthref1054
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#sthref2351
http://psoug.org/reference/pipelined.html
http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/pl_sql/htdocs/x/Table_Functions_Cursor_Expressions/Pipelined_Table_Functions.htm

Comment: how table functions perform against views or subqueries ?

Comment: They are a bit slower I think, but it depends on what exactly you do.

Comment: This IS the best solution, it just took me a while to explain it to the stakeholder. The links help.

Answer (score 0):

- UPDATED #2

The only date parameter there is on this line

```
t.end_date < current_date
```

So there is all you need to change without changing the inner query.
If you mean that the view is

```
CREATE VIEW v1
as
select 
  some_id
from 
  tablename t
where 
  t.end_date < current_date
  and not exists (
    select null
    from tablename ti
    where ti.end_date > t.end_date
      and ti.some_id = t.some_id
      and ti.some_criteria = t.some_criteria
  )
```

And you want to be able to use something like this

```
select * from v1 where end_date < current_date-7
```

Not sure if Oracle can inline the filter into the view, but you can try this (remove the filter).
A function may work better than a view though.

```
CREATE VIEW v1
as
select 
  some_id
from 
  tablename t
where not exists (
    select null
    from tablename ti
    where ti.end_date > t.end_date
      and ti.some_id = t.some_id
      and ti.some_criteria = t.some_criteria
  )
```

Comment: I agree. I don't see anything in the sub-query that would need to be changed

Comment: The OP says he *doesn't want to replace `current_value`* when he calls the query, so it can go in a view.

Comment: djacobson is correct, changing it to the above would always get me the most recently ended t, (I realize that this makes the current_date filter in the outer query mostly irrelevant) regardless of what I filtered it as.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package variable and a package function along with the view. The package variable is set at the session level so can be different for different sessions.

Create the package spec

```
create or replace package pkg_current_date is

  current_date date;
  function get_current_date return date;

end pkg_current_date;
```

And the package body:

```
create or replace package body pkg_current_date is

    function get_current_date return date is

  begin
    return current_date;
  end;


end pkg_current_date;
```

Then use the function you created within a view

```
CREATE VIEW v1
as
select 
  some_id
from 
  tablename t
where 
  t.end_date < pkg_current_date.get_current_date;
```

To query the view, just set the date and then query. It would probably pay to set some sort of default date otherwise the view will return nothing as `current_date` will be null.

```
begin
  pkg_current_date.current_date := date '2010-01-01'
end;

select * from v1
```